# Proving Properties of Poisson in limit of Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a property that depends on a distribution, and I have been able to show it holds whenever the distribution is of the form $Bin(k,\frac{\mu}{k})$, and I would like to show it holds also for $Poi(\mu)$ by taking the limit. The analysis for the binomials relied on the fact that the random variable can only take finitely many values, but now I am not sure what to do since it is infinite.
Any tips or pointing towards related work is extremely helpful!

Comment: Could you maybe share with us what kind of property you are trying to prove? Is it too complicated?

Comment: The answer will depend on the property. Some properties are preserved in the limit, others are not.

Answer (score 0):

> Theorem: If X and Y are two rv's with $F_X(x)$; $F_Y(y)$ and with existing MGF $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$, then

$F_X(\cdot)\equiv F_Y(\cdot) \iff M_X(\cdot) \equiv M_Y(\cdot)$

The MGF of the binomial is, setting as usual $p=\frac{\lambda}{n}$

$[1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+\frac{\lambda}{n}e^t]^n$

Let's calculate the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}[1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+\frac{\lambda}{n}e^t]^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}[1+\frac{\lambda(e^t-1)}{n}]^n=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$$

Now we immediately recognize the MGF of a Poisson $\lambda$

$$M_Y(t)=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$$